# How to highlight a menu item after it is routed to its particular menu?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How to highlight a (in side-nav) menu item (on selected) after it is routed to its particular menu in angular material? It will be useful if anyone got the solution.

```html
<md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" 
  md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">  
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="customer">test1</a>
    </menu-link>
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="project">test2</a>
    </menu-link>
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="material">test3</a>
    </menu-link>
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="boq">test6</a>
    </menu-link>
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="supplier">test8</a>
    </menu-link>
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="order">test10</a>
    </menu-link>
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="invoice">test78</a>
    </menu-link> 
    <menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple active" ui-sref="enquiry">test89</a>
    </menu-link> 
</md-sidenav>
```

Comment: The first step is to pick the CSS that you want for the highlighted button. See [Angular Material CSS - Button](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/button).

Answer (score 0):

Add `ui-sref-active="active"` to every link. See the example below.

```
<menu-link section="page" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <a class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ui-sref="customer" ui-sref-active="active">
        test1
    </a>
</menu-link>
```

The link will have an `active` class when the user is on the route specified in `ui-sref` or its child route. You can use that class to style the active item in any way you want.